# magento2 remove field in customer create in backend

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

In backend customer, when i want create new customer in customer/index/new, i want remove field Name Prefix

[image]

in file di.xml i have

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit">
        <plugin name="disable_customer_field" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\EditPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

and i have file php

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Customer\Block\Adminhtml;

class EditPlugin
{
    public function beforeSetForm(
        \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form
    ) {
        $form->getElement('prefix')->setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

But i not working, can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Override the **customer_form.xml** file in your module.

Add following code in **{Your Module Path}\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="prefix" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi but can we have another way to check in php to i can check the session?

Answer (score 0):

The `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit` class is deprecated and no longer used for the customer edit/create page in the admin.

To remove a field in the customer create and edit page in the admin, you'll need to override the field declared in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` file.

In your case, modify the page in **the admin area**, you'll need to put your file in the `adminhtml` directory.

To remove the **Name Prefix**, create `<your module dir>/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml` file with the following content.
Example: `app/code/TuVan/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="prefix" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

---

**To remove a field in the customer create and edit page in the admin based on a condition in PHP**, you need to modify the `getMeta()` method in the **DataProvider** class of the UI form component.

The DataProvider of the **Customer form** is declared in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` file:

```
<dataProvider class="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProviderWithDefaultAddresses" name="customer_form_data_source">
```

Implementation:

1. Create a `di.xml` in the **admin area**: `<your module dir>/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`.
   Example: `app/code/TuVan/Customer/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProviderWithDefaultAddresses">
        <plugin name="manage_prefix_field_visibility" type="TuVan\Customer\Plugin\ManagePrefixFieldVisibility"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Create plugin class: `<your module dir>/Plugin/ManagePrefixFieldVisibility.php`.
   Example: `app/code/TuVan/Customer/Plugin/ManagePrefixFieldVisibility.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace TuVan\Customer\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProviderWithDefaultAddresses;

/**
 * Plugin for managing prefix field in Customer form Data Provider in the admin area.
 */
class ManagePrefixFieldVisibility
{
    public function afterGetMeta(
        DataProviderWithDefaultAddresses $subject,
        array $result
    ): array {
        $isDisabledPrefixField = false;
        if (1==1) {//Remember to change this condition
            $isDisabledPrefixField = true;
        }

        $config = [
            'customer' => [
                'children' => [
                    'prefix' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'componentDisabled' => $isDisabledPrefixField
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return array_replace_recursive($result, $config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi but can we have another way to check in php to i can check the session?

Comment: @Boll I have added the solution for that.